# Woocommerce "No Shipping methods" message: Customise message based on the Zipcode customer enters

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Our store has been setup to process orders only within Sydney city. We manage this in Woocommerce by setting the allowed postcodes for a Flat Rate Delivery.
We are now extending deliveries to other other areas but only via telephone (no online orders for these new postcodes). Woocommerce displays a standard No Shipping message but we would to customise such that

- Customer enters a postcode within the city, allow online orders. No
  change to current behaviour.
- Customer enters a postcode for which
  telephone orders are allowed, show a customised message asking the
  customer to make the call.
- All other postcodes, disallow orders.

Any technical direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code should help you. Change the value of array variable $zip_array in both the functions as a comma separated list of zip codes, which you want to show a custom message. Also, change the string value of $custom_msg to your custom message. More details, please refer [this article](http://support.wooforce.com/hc/en-us/articles/208544165).

```
// For Cart Page.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_no_shipping_available_html', 'wf_customize_default_message', 10, 1 );
// For Checkout page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_no_shipping_available_html', 'wf_customize_default_message', 10, 1 );
function wf_customize_default_message( $default_msg ) {
    $zip_array = array(
        '30031',
    );

    if ( in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode() , $zip_array) ) {
        $custom_msg = "Call us for quotation - 1-800-XXX-XXXX";
        if( empty( $custom_msg ) ) {
          return $default_msg;
        }
        return $custom_msg;
    }

    return $default_msg;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'wf_remove_shipping_options_for_particular_zip_codes', 8, 2);
function wf_remove_shipping_options_for_particular_zip_codes($rates, $package)
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $zip_array = array(
        '30031',
    );
    if ( in_array( $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_postcode() , $zip_array) ) {
        $rates = array();
    }

    return $rates;
}
```